Is there a program for generating a "diff" file of 2 directories, containing all the "changes" but none of the original directory's file contents?
I've been making some modifications to a proprietary open source software (upon purchase the software ships with the source code but its not "shareware").
I would like to be able to share my modifications with other users of the program, without "leaking" the original soure code (so that other users have to go buy & download the program from the original author - and then somehow apply my changes) - hence, my question in the title. Is there a program (available for Windows 11) for generating a "diff" file of 2 directories or .zip files, containing all the "changes" but none of the original directory's file contents?
A lot of the changes I've made are in existing files (in fact, Ive modified all the source files at this point, lol), so the software Im seeking needs to be able to generate some kind of per line "diff" rather than just dumping entire text documents.
If there is no such program
I also have a bit of a moralically questionable question: If I were to encrypt my program with SHA-256, using the hash of the zipped (.zip) original program as key, could I simply share that with other users and feel comfortable that no one will be able to decrypt it without obtaining the zip used as key? If so, how long would the key have to be, could I simply use Pythons hash()
function on the string of the zip to generate the key and call it a day? I've also never encrypted anything before so I wouldn't mind some kind of advice on encryption programs as well :)
Thank you.

Turns out what I was looking for is called "binary delta compression":

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_delta_compression
https://github.com/google/open-vcdiff
https://github.com/sisong/HDiffPatch


Please improve your answer by giving  some more information on what they do.
